# Python run a Linux command and then leave the terminal to user

Tags: python, linux, authentication, subprocess

I am writing a remote login script that should just run a command (log me in to a device via telnet or ssh) and then just leave the terminal to me.

I tried `subrocess.Popen` module and for windows host I managed to achieve what I needed, the script opens putty or SecureCRT via a cmd command logging me in and then stops leaving the window to me.

In Linux it's a little different though, I want the script to run a command in the terminal and then I should be able to continue working on the terminal myself. I tried `subrocess` with not much luck.

I can achieve this with `pexpect.interact()` but it seems that it will be more efficient if after logging me in the python script stopped as it is not needed anymore, if it is possible of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pwntools` http://docs.pwntools.com/en/latest/intro.html#making-connections

It has a nice `interactive` mode.

Check the examples on the page I linked.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ron. If I understood this correctly pwntools archives similar result as pexpect, while what i am trying make Python open a session for me and then exit, leaving the session open... if it is even possible of course.